# How to configure db2 in jasper report server?

Tags: jasperserver

i want to know how to configure db2 in jasper report server. Can you tell me step by step?.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DB2 JDBC driver here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

The DB2 URL should be:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/jsprsrvr:driverType=4;
    fullyMaterializeLobData=true;fullyMaterializeInputStreams=true;
    progressiveStreaming=2;progresssiveLocators=2;currentSchema=JSPRSRVR
```

Modify JSPRSRVR with the schema you want to connect.
The driver class you will use is:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

For configuring datasources, here you have a step-by-step guide http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/DataSources

Comment: May you show me more details?.i still don't know how to follow your instruction because my default files after i install the jasper report server using mysql. i don't know how to combine  2 datasource.